# What should be the regex to match < except for mark tag?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, regex

Basically I need to match any **<** from a text that isn't part of a `<mark>` or `</mark>` tag. This is what I got so far, but it doesn't really work as expected and I've been trying for some time now.

`/(<)(?=[^mark]|$)/g`

I need the regex to work in Javascript.

I would like it to match every < except for the ones come in the mark tags.

like the < which are in ** should match in the below example.

As an example:

```
hello, <mark id="abc-Def">how</mark> are you?
where **<**span>are**<**/span> you <mark>from</mark>?
**<**noice id="jk">product**<**/noice>
```

Comment: Your problem is parsing HTML, so you've chosen regexes as a solution.   Now you have two problems...

Comment: @Alnitak because of the use case.

Comment: `<(?!(mark|\/mark))` should be enough

Comment: Addition: To get the > other than mark tag we can use /(?<![^<]*<\/?mark\b[^>]*)>/g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
/<(?!\/?mark\b[^>]*>)/gi
```

Replace with `**$&**`. See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/7Q3oAn/1/).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/?                      '/' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mark                     'mark'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^>]*                    any character except: '>' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    >                        '>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

JavaScript:

```js
const text = `hello, <mark id="abc-Def">how</mark> are you?
where <span>are</span> you <mark>from</mark>?
<noice id="jk">product</noice>`;
console.log(text.replace(/<(?!\/?mark\b[^>]*>)/gi, `**$&**`));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?   /<(?!(mark|/mark))/

Comment: sam-andreatta @mat-j 
it won't work for some tags which contain mark in starting like <markup>...